# Enable soft wrap filtered by extension in Atom Editor

Tags: text-editors, atom-editor

I am working with "text file formats" (like `.md` and `.tex`), as well as with "real programming languages".

I would like to have soft wrapping enabled only for a set of files, for example, `.md`, `.tex`, but not for `.c`, `.h`, `.cpp`, `.py`.

Now, I found that I could open my `config.cson` and create the next line

```
"*":
  "editor":
    "softWrap": true
```

but this, unfortunately, enables soft wraps for every file and they look awkward for C, Go, Python source files.

Atom soft wraps by default all `.md` files, even if the above configuration option is not included in the `config.cson` file. I would like to have soft wraps for my tex files to. How can I achieve this?

[image: atom soft wraps md files, but not tex files]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find which package (scope?) controls the files you want to treat differently. The [Atom Manual's "Basic Customization" page, "Language Specific Configuration Settings" section](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#language-specific-configuration-settings)  brings an example for this kind of customization that can be controlled from both the Settings View and the `config.cson` configuration file.

In my case, what I needed to do is adding the next lines to my config file

```
".text.plain":
  "editor":
    "softWrap": true
```

As I later installed [`yudai-nkt/language-tex`](https://github.com/yudai-nkt/language-tex) package, I added

```
".latex.tex.text":
  editor:
    softWrap: true
```

These settings can be also modified from within the Atom GUI:

```
Edit
└─ Preferences
   └─ Packages
       └─(search for your language, pick a package)
          └─> Settings
```